# Python interact with OS cmd

Tags: python, cmd, python-os

I would like to know if it was possible via the OS module to iterate on several lines with the command prompt
Here is an example of what I would have liked to do but which does not work (non-persistent session):

```py
from os import popen, system, getlogin

system(f'cd C:/Users/{getlogin()}')
print(popen('pip freeze'))
```

Comment: The function [os.system](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) is deprecated since Python 3.0 which means since many years. It should not be used anymore in newly written Python scripts. There is the [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html). It is on Windows a Python wrapper module for the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) which is used by `cmd.exe`, `explorer.exe`, `cscript.exe`, `powershell.exe`, etc. to run an executable.

Comment: The `subprocess` module gives a Python script writer full control over all parameters and the values in the [STARTUPINFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfow) structure used to define the environment for the execution of the executable. There is the function parameter `cwd` which is short for __current working directory__ which is passed to `CreateProcess` with the function parameter `lpCurrentDirectory`. It is much better to run the executable with `subprocess` with `cwd` specified with the current user´s profile directory.

Comment: [os.environ](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ) documents how to get the string value of an environment variable like `USERPROFILE` which means there can be used `cwd=os.environ["USERPROFILE"]` to define the current working directory already by `CreateProcess` on starting the executable making the usage of the internal command __CD__ of `cmd.exe` not necessary at all. Well, there is not even necessary to run `cmd.exe` at all because of the Python script can use `subprocess.run()` (=`CreateProcess`) as often as needed to do the same as `cmd.exe` using also `CreateProcess`.

Comment: It is wrong by design to code a Python script interpreted by one of the most powerful script interpreters nowadays to start the Windows Command Processor `cmd.exe` being the oldest and at least powerful script interpreter still used on modern operating systems and try to communicate with `cmd.exe` from within the Python script via the standard input, output and error stream. `cmd.exe` is designed to run internal commands of `cmd.exe` and executables one after the other. `cmd` is not designed to interact with any other process. Using `cmd` from within a Python script is always wrong by design.

Answer (score 1):

I tested this on Windows and it worked with `check_output` from `subprocess`, using `cmd /C` to execute both commands and exit

```
from os import getlogin
from subprocess import check_output

cmd_str = fr'cmd.exe /C "cd C:\Users\{getlogin()} && pip freeze"'

output = check_output(cmd_str, shell=True).decode()
for line in output.split('\r\n'):
    print(line)
```

output:

```
absl-py==1.3.0
aiohttp==3.7.3
altgraph==0.17
astroid==2.4.2
astunparse==1.6.3
.....
```

Comment: Your solution only use one line so yes it works but for longer code it will not, it's the same as: `popen(f"C:/Users/{getlogin()}/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/Scripts/pip freeze").read()` Btw i would like to know why python with popen does'nt find pip.exe defined in system path variables?

Comment: You need to set shell=True? in my system pip is in 'C:\Python\Python38\Scripts\pip.exe'